# Uploading image larger than rich text area field max size limit of 131072 characters is failing

Tags: bulk-api-v2

I am unable to upload base64 encoded image string larger than 131072 characters through Bulk v2 API into a Rich text area field.

I am using the folloing text while uploading.

```
<img alt="<image_Name>" src="data:image/<image_File_Extension>;base64, <base64_Image_String>"></img>
```

If I have an image whose base64 encoded value is larger than 131072 chars, what is the best way to upload such an image programatically (using Bulk / REST API) ?

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible at all.

Rich text area cannot have more than 131072 characters, which means you cannot insert a text or html which has more than that into the value of this field.

Instead you should consider splitting it up or upload an image as ContentVersion and paste a link to ContentVersion inside the field or choose Attachment or other way for storage so that you don't have 131072 characters inside rich text area field.